# Rounding error in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am stuck.... why do these two queries return different results?

```
declare @div varchar
set @div = cast(4/3.0 as varchar) 
select @div
-- returns 1 

select cast(4/3.0 as varchar)
-- returns 1.3333
```

Comment: Find more informations about this behavior in this post
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10824/column-length-and-data-length.aspx

Comment: Please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Because your declaring the varchar without length. ie

```
declare @div varchar
```

is the same as

```
declare @div varchar(1)
```

Comment: @littlegreen Get into the habit of always defining varchar (and nvarchar) with length.